# CASE WHEN with Multiple conditions

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am trying to create new column using following conditions in MySQL Workbench.

I tried to write a code to get new column (output) and it should be like:
IF Asian is Yes Then Asian
IF Black is Yes Then Black
**IF Black is Yes AND Other is Yes Then Black**
IF White is Yes Then White
IF Hispanic is Yes Then Hispanic
**IF Hispanic is Yes AND Other is Yes Then Hispanic**
IF Pacific is Yes Then Pacific
IF Middle is Yes Then Middle
IF Other is Yes Then Other
IF **More than One reported Then Multiple** (expect Black and Other is Yes and Hispanic and Other is Yes)
ELSE Notreported

```
  CREATE TABLE Test(
                ID INT NOT NULL,
                Asian CHAR(7),
                Black CHAR(9),
                White CHAR(6),
                Hispanic CHAR(5),
                Pacific CHAR(7),
                Middle CHAR(9),
                Other CHAR(6)
                );
```

```
insert into Test values 
    (1,'Yes','No','No','No', 'No','No','No'),
    (2,'No','Yes','No','No', 'No','No','No'),
    (3,'No','No','Yes','No', 'No','No','No'),
    (4,'No','No','No','Yes', 'No','No','No'),
    (5,'No','No','No','No', 'Yes','No','No'),
    (6,'No','No','No','No', 'No','Yes','No'),
    (7,'No','No','No','No', 'No','No','Yes'),
    (8,'No','No','No','No', 'Yes','No','Yes'),
    (9,'No','Yes','No','No', 'No','No','Yes'),
    (10,'Yes','Yes','Yes','No', 'No','No','Yes'),
    (11,'No','No','Yes','Yes', 'No','No','Yes'),
    (12,'No','No','No','Yes', 'No','No','Yes'),
    (13,'No','Yes','No','No', 'No','No','Yes')
    ;
```

```
Select ID, Asian, Black, White, Hispanic, Pacific, Middle, Other,
case
    when Asian='Yes' then
        case 
            when Black='No' then 'Asian'
            when White='No' then 'Asian'
            when Hispanic='No' then 'Asian'
            when Pacific='No' then 'Asian'
            when Middle='No' then 'Asian'
            when Other='No' then 'Asian'
        end
    When Black='Yes' then
        case
            when Asian='No' then 'Black'
            when White='No' then 'Black'
            when Hispanic='No' then 'Black'
            when Pacific='No' then 'Black'
            when Middle='No' then 'Black'
            when Other='Yes' then 'Black'
        end
    When White='Yes' then
        case
            when Asian='No' then 'White'
            when Black='No' then 'White'
            when Hispanic='No' then 'White'
            when Pacific='No' then 'White'
            when Middle='No' then 'White'
            when Other='No' then 'White'
        end
    When Hispanic='Yes' then
        case
            when Asian='No' then 'Hispanic'
            when Black='No' then 'Hispanic'
            when White='No' then 'Hispanic'
            when Pacific='No' then 'Hispanic'
            when Middle='No' then 'Hispanic'
            when Other='Yes' then 'Hispanic'
        end
    When Pacific='Yes' then
        case
            when Asian='No' then 'Pacific'
            when Black='No' then 'Pacific'
            when White='No' then 'Pacific'
            when Hispanic='No' then 'Pacific'
            when Middle='No' then 'Pacific'
            when Other='No' then 'Pacific'
        end
    When Middle='Yes' then
        case
            when Asian='No' then 'Middle'
            when Black='No' then 'Middle'
            when White='No' then 'Middle'
            when Hispanic='No' then 'Middle'
            when Pacific='No' then 'Middle'
            when Other='No' then 'Middle'
        end
    When Other='Yes' then
        case
            when Asian='No' then 'Other'
            when Black='No' then 'Other'
            when White='No' then 'Other'
            when Hispanic='No' then 'Other'
            when Pacific='No' then 'Other'
            when Middle='No' then 'Other'
        end
    else 'Multiple'
end AS Race
FROM Test;
```

I did not get 'Multiple'. Your help and input will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: The way you have your outer `CASE` statement structured, you will only get 'Multiple' if there is a record where Asian='No', White='No', Black='No', etc. For all the test records you showed, there is at least one 'Yes', which means one of the inner `CASE` statements will be evaluated.

Comment: The problem is your table design.

Comment: The problem is decribed clearly by kosmer. With `case when Asian='Yes' then ... When Black='Yes' then ...  When White='Yes' then ... else 'Multiple'` you get 'Multiple' for all rows where none of the values is 'Yes', and there is no such row in the table shown. I don't consider the table design *the* problem hence, but as you want to detect certain combinations, working with this table will become rather clumsy, and it would be better to have a table with one row per ID and attribute instead, so you could simply aggregate.

Comment: If it were me, I'd have 2 columns of `ID, Ethnicity` only with a `PRIMARY KEY(ID, Ethnicity)` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in your description you are using some `AND`, but in your query you don't. E.g. you say:

> IF Black is Yes AND Other is Yes Then Black

but there is no according `case when Black = 'Yes' and Other = 'No' then` in the query

The second problem is that you are not using enough `AND` in your description. E.g.:

> IF Asian is Yes Then Asian

No. If Asian is Yes Then Either Asian or Multiple. So what you really want to say is:

> If Asian is Yes AND White is No AND Black is No AND Hispanic is No AND Pacific is No AND Middle is No AND Other is No Then Asian

If you are precise when describing the task, it is often easy to translate this into SQL. In your example we could almost use the exact description word for word. And this is how your query would look like then:

```
Select
  ID, Asian, Black, White, Hispanic, Pacific, Middle, Other,
  case
    when Asian = 'Yes'
    and White = 'No' 
    and Black = 'No' 
    and Hispanic = 'No' 
    and Pacific = 'No' 
    and Middle = 'No' 
    and Other = 'No' 
      then 'Asian'
    when Asian = 'No'
    and White = 'No' 
    and Black = 'Yes' 
    and Hispanic = 'No' 
    and Pacific = 'No' 
    and Middle = 'No' 
      then 'Black'
    ...
```

This would be way shorter with another data model, though. Let's say your table is about persons, i.e. the ID is a person ID. Then you would have a table `person` containing one row per person with their name and so on, a table `attribute` containing one row per attribute ('Asian', 'White', etc.) and one table relating a person with their attributes: `person_attribute (person_id, attribute_id)`.

You could then query the table thus:

```
select
  pa.person_id,
  case 
    when count(*) = 1 and max(a.attribute = 'Asian') then 'Asian'
    when count(*) = 1 and max(a.attribute = 'Black') then 'Black'
    when count(*) = 2 and min(a.attribute = 'Black') and max(a.attribute = 'Other') then 'Black'
    ...
    else 'Multiple'
  end as race
from person_attribute pa
join attribute a on a.attributeid = pa.attribute_id
group by pa.person_id;
```

Comment: Thank you Thorsten.